# Bitmap/Canvas getting cached when exiting activity

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm creating a canvas on a WebView like so (below). I'm implementing an undo function so the user can remove drawn paths with a button click. The canvas, however, is always populated with my paths even if I leave the activity and return. The only way to remove it is to close the app. How do I remove or re-create the bitmap `canvasBitmap` or canvas `drawCanvas`

```
public static Canvas drawCanvas;
public static Bitmap canvasBitmap;
Rect clipBounds;

public static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
public static ArrayList<Paint> colors = new ArrayList<Paint>();

// Creates bitmap for canvas
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

// Saves the paths onto the bitmap and adjust scale based on current zoom level
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(8/mScaleFactor);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), colors.get(i));
    }
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    invalidate();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    float touchX = (event.getX() + clipBounds.left) / mScaleFactor;
    float touchY = (event.getY() + clipBounds.top) / mScaleFactor;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 Paint newPaint = new Paint();
                newPaint.set(drawPaint); //copies the values over from the current class's paint
                colors.add(newPaint);
                paths.add(drawPath);
                drawPath = new Path();
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public void reDrawUndo () {
     if (paths.size() > 0) {
         paths.remove(paths.size() - 1);
         colors.remove(colors.size() - 1);
         invalidate();
     }
}
```

I'm drawing the paths with the corresponding colors onto the canvas with this method:

```
for (int j = 0; j < paths.size(); j++) {
    drawCanvas.drawPath(paths.get(j),colors.get(j));
           }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but your code doesn't look fine to me. When something looks the same when you close the activity it means that you use static variables. Why your drawCanvas and canvasBitmap are static? BTW are you sure you need this drawCanvas? Isn't the canvas from onDraw method enough for you?

Comment: If I don't explicitly do `drawCanvas.drawPath` my bitmap `canvasBitmap` is empty when I try to save it, even though there are visible paths on the screen as I draw them.

Comment: Ok I don't understand why you need this in onDraw(): canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

Im not sure if that's the point but you should draw all the paths + drawpath on a canvas in onDraw and when you want to "save" you mean like a bitmap save? Then create a new bitmap with it's canvas - draw it one more time and save the bitmap. If I understand what you are trying to do I think it should be that way :)

Comment: Yes, but I'm a little confused with the `canvas.drawPath` and `drawCanvas.drawPath`. If I include both of them in the `onDraw` I'll have paths overlaying each other. If I save the bitmap `canvasBitmap`, it will be empty unless I do `drawCanvas.drawPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your points you keep on a list "paths" and you hold currently drawn path "drawPath": This is your "logic".

When you want to see them on the screen you draw them in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method on a provided canvas: This is your logic drawn on the UI.

When you want to save your points you can have few options it depends on what you want to achieve. When you want to save a bitmap with your paths drawn on it - you create a new bitmap (you dont have to keep it in memory the whole time) and a canvas for it and you draw all the points on your new canvas. When you want to save the points so that they could be drawn later just save them as integers or text in a file or database.

Comment: Yes. It was the issue with static variables. I just created a new instance of the class and added some getters for the bitmap and canvas instead of making them static.